# 'Object is not a function' - onclick event

Tags: javascript, function, syntax-error

Before I start, no I have no issues that I can find with semicolons, and I'm passing NO values to the function.

When I try to do function "login()" from the console, it works just fine, but when I click an HTML input button to call it, I get "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function". This is in Chrome by the way.

```
var aj=new XMLHttpRequest();
var loginf=document.forms["login"];
var regf=document.forms["reg"];

function login(){
var errors=document.getElementById("login_err");
var errs=[];
var uname=loginf['uname'];
var pass=loginf['pass'];
var unameVal=uname.value;
var passVal=pass.value;

if(unameVal.length<4 && unameVal.length>0){
    errs.push("Username too short. Try again please.");
}
else if(unameVal.length>18){
    errs.push(innerHTML="Username is too long. Try again please.");
}
else if(unameVal.length==0){
    errs.push("Please enter a username.");
}

if(passVal.length<8){
    errs.push("Password too short. Try again, please.");
}
else if(passVal.length>30){
    errs.push("Password is too long. Try again please.");
}

if(errs.length==0){
    aj.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(aj.readyState>=4 && aj.status==200){
            if(aj.responseText=="suc"){
                window.location="/new.php";
            }
        }
    }
    aj.open("POST","/inc/php/core.php",false);
    aj.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    aj.send("login=true&data="+data);
}
else{
    errors.innerHTML="<ul>";

    for(var x=0;x<errs.length;x++){
        errors.innerHTML+="<li>"+errs[x]+"</li>";
    }

    errors.innerHTML+="</ul>";
}
}

function reg(){

}
```

And then the input button..

```
<input type="button" class="submit" value="Log in" style="width:25%" onclick="login();"/>
```

I see nothing wrong with the code.

Thank you in advance if you can find Waldo in this code.

jsFiddle HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/6sa7M/2

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could give us a jsfiddle

Comment: On what line? What's the stack trace?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints

Comment: Why are `aj`, `loginf` and `regf` declared as global variables? Move them into the login() function so they are local (this could be causing issues).

Comment: You probably have a DOM element with "login" as his id

Comment: Benjamin-The error is on the line of the input button itself, which leads me to believe that it's something having to do with the "onclick" attribute. 

Sudipta-I'll make an edit with a jsFiddle

Comment: loginf and regf don't HAVE to be global, but I'd prefer having aj global because it saves me time so that I don't have to write out 2 different XMLHttpRequests.

Comment: Ateszki-Yes, I DO have a div that contains the form itself with an id of "login". I changed it to "login_form" on my site and the fiddle and it still doesn't work.

Comment: When you call document.forms[login] whats the id of that form? And the name? Can you change it?

Comment: document.forms['login'] is a reference to the form, which, by the way, has the NAME of "login", not the ID.

Comment: Move the script to the head and change the name of the function so that it does not collide with an element id. Notice, not the form with the _name_ login, the div with the _id_ login is a collision.

Comment: Try to change the name of the form or the function

Answer (score 7):

It turns out that the function name "login" was both a reference to the form and function.

I changed "login()" to "loginUser()", and typed "login" into the console, and the form was returned, so they were indeed conflicting with each other.

Thank you again for all the help and special thanks to Marc for the true answer.

Comment: You can easily avoid these sorts of collisions by putting all your identifiers under a single namespace.